# Database design for a reservation system with assets which can travel between locations

Tags: database, database-design

I'm developing a database structure which consists of assets which travel between a couple of locations. I want to make a reservation system for these assets. If assets don't travel between the different locations it's very easy to get the availability: just check how many reservations for a certain day exists and substract them from the normally available number assets.

```
available = Normal.Available - already reserved
```

But the complicating factor is the fact people can travel between different locations. A customer can pick up an asset at Location A and drop it of at Location B. For instance pickup on september 13th 10:00am dropoff at LocB september 13th 13:00.

If I now want to have the available assets at Location B at 13:00 this is the normal available number +1 because of the asset which travelled from A->B. The availability at location A is one less then normal, obviously.

**How can I graph these movements in a database structure?**
The entities are clear: Assets, locations, bookings and Customers. The difficulty lies within getting the availability at the different locations at different times.

Comment: Say each asset is available for 15 reservation per day. this means that you have 15 instances of that asset. Do You maintain each instance individually in asset table or One asset with number of available instances as field in asset table?

Comment: We have multiple assets available which can be rented out during the day (or even overnight). Standard we have lets say 3 assets available per location. I don't know what is wise to do. Maybe it's better to have a table with availability per asset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
assets
    id              unsigned int(P)
    description     varchar(200)

+----+-------------+
| id | description |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | Widget A    |
| .. | ........... |
+----+-------------+
```

See [PHP's crypt() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) for hashing the password.

```
customers
    id              unsigned int(P)
    first_name      varchar(50)
    middle_name     varchar(50) // Allow NULL
    last_name       varchar(50)
    email           varchar(255)
    username        varchar(32)
    password        varbinary(255) // hashed
    ...

+----+------------+-------------+-----------+----------------------------+-----------+----------+-----+
| id | first_name | middle_name | last_name | email                      | username  | password | ... |
+----+------------+-------------+-----------+----------------------------+-----------+----------+-----+
|  1 | John       | Quincy      | Public    | jqp@privacy.com            | johnqball | xxxxxxxx | ... |
|  2 | Jane       | NULL        | Doe       | ladyinred@chrisdeburgh.com | janeykins | xxxxxxxx | ... |
| .. | .......... | ........... | ......... | .......................... | ......... | .......  | ... |
+----+------------+-------------+-----------+----------------------------+-----------+----------+-----+

locations
    id              unsigned int(P)
    description     varchar(200)

+----+-------------+
| id | description |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | Facility A  |
|  2 | Facility B  |
| .. | ........... |
+----+-------------+

reservations
    id              unsigned int(P)
    asset_id        unsigned int(F assets.id)
    customer_id     unsigned int(F customers.id)
    from_id         unsigned int(F locations.id)
    to_id           unsigned int(F locations.id)
    beg             datetime
    end             datetime

+----+-------------+----------+---------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | customer_id | asset_id | from_id | to_id |         beg         |         end         |
+----+-------------+----------+---------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |           1 |        1 |       1 |     2 | 2013-09-13 03:00:00 | 2013-09-13 14:00:00 |
|  1 |           1 |        1 |       2 |     1 | 2013-09-14 19:00:00 | 2013-09-15 07:00:00 |
|  1 |           1 |        1 |       1 |     2 | 2013-09-15 10:00:00 | 2013-09-15 17:00:00 |
|  1 |           1 |        1 |       2 |     1 | 2013-09-16 08:00:00 | 2013-09-16 13:00:00 |
|  1 |           1 |        1 |       1 |     2 | 2013-09-17 10:00:00 | 2013-09-17 17:00:00 |
| .. | ........... | ........ | ....... | ..... | ................... | ................... |
+----+-------------+----------+---------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

To find out what's available right now at Facility A:

```
SELECT DISTINCT asset_id, * FROM reservations
WHERE to_id = 1 AND
    beg > NOW()
ORDER BY beg, end
```

To find out what's available tomorrow at 15:00 at Facility B:

```
$target_datetime = '2013-09-14 15:00:00';
SELECT DISTINCT asset_id, * FROM reservations
WHERE to_id = 2 AND
    beg > $target_datetime
ORDER BY beg, end
```

Comment: Here you have only one reservation per asset he may have many reservation per asset at the same time as I understand

Comment: @Tassadaque with the solution of Benny Hill every asset would have an own row in the asset table.

Comment: @Benny Hill: What if there is an other reservation of asset_id=1 in on the 15th of september. It would show up at the last query but that's not correct.

Comment: @stUrb - I added some data to the reservations table and modified the queries to only return one result.

Comment: Thumbs up benny! I was just thinking in the wrong direction with an location-with-assets view. Instead of the assets seperately which can only be on one location at a time :)

Comment: But the limit is not correct. If there are two assets transferred to location 2 they will not show up there. Shouldn't there be a group-by on the asset_id?

Comment: @stUrb - I updated the SQL. Sorry about the edits, work keeps interrupting me :-) By adding the `DISTINCT` I insure we will only see each asset listed once which is what I was thinking when I added the `LIMIT` (but was obviously wrong!).

Comment: That should do the trick indeed! Thanks for the help! This sounds pretty solid and workable! Thank you.

Comment: After a night sleep I found two issues with this query/scheme: 1 - the `beg > $target-datetime` should be the `end` time because the asset is not at the to_location at the beginning time. Secondly if, lets say I want to make a reservation from 15:00-17:00 on sept 14th then I need to run the query as above to get the assets on locationB at a certain starting point. But after that I'll need another query to check if the asset is available for the selected period. Right?

Answer (score 1):

if you maintaining each asset availability as asset Instance then you may create a table `AssetInstances(AssetInstanceID,AssetID)`

the reservation table would be

```
AssetMovement(AssetInstanceID, FromLocationID,ToLocationID,StartMovementTime,EndMovementTime,CustomerID)
```

Now ToLocation is the current place of instance you can get the location wise instance count based on `max(movementtime) group by AssetID` `ToLocationID` will be null in case of asset is in transit

In case you are maintaining one asset per row there is no instance table then AssetMovement table may be like

```
AssetMovement(AssetID, FromLocationID,ToLocationID,StartMovementTime,EndMovementTime,CustomerID,IsCurrentReservation)
```

Now if asset is picked by customer from location A `IsCurrenReservation` will be true and when he drop and location B `IsCurrenReservation` still remains true. Now say it is again picked from Location B then `IsCurrenReservation` will be true for this and previous  entery's `IsCurrenReservation` will be false. Now in query with `IsCurrenReservation= true` will give you the current number of  assets per location. and if TolocationID is null and IsCurrentReservation=true will give you number of reservation at any time. This may not be an ideal solution but looks like it will work

Answer (score 0):

What I see is 4 entities to start with : **Asset**, **Location**, **Customer** and **Booking**.
Use Booking to show what time what asset is booked by a customer from one location to another.

Comment: Yeah I normalized those entities already; but the difficulty lies in getting the availability on different times on the different locations.

Comment: @stUrb Just count the number of assets dropped at a location minus the ones picked up from there before the time of interest.